# Application level monitoring in Tomcat using Zabbix/Nagios

Tags: tomcat, nagios, zabbix

I am pretty comfortable with Nagios and a newbie in Zabbix. I have a tomcat in which I have deployed 3 war files. I am able to monitor the Tomcat as such using Nagios but I am not able to monitor the individual status of the 3 applications. Is it possible to individually monitor those applications using Nagios/Zabbix ?

Information regarding either of them would be amazing, but I would personally like it in Nagios since I am used to it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are connecting to Tomcat (or whatever application server) using JMX, I'd recommend you  to monitor the status of your application using jmx too.

In zabbix you'd have to create an item for every metric you want to monitor.

In your application you have to register a MBean.

```
public void registerNotikumiMBean(String app){
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    Hashtable<String, String> tb = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    tb.put("type", "yourcustomtype");
    tb.put("subtype", "yourcustomid");
    ObjectName on = null;
    try {
        on = new ObjectName("your.pa.cka.ge", tb);
        YourCustomBean mbean = new YourCustom();
        mBeanServer.registerMBean(mbean, on);

    } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
    } catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) {
    } catch (MBeanRegistrationException e) {
    } catch (NotCompliantMBeanException e) {
    }
}
```

You can find everything you need about mbeans in link below
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/standard.html

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your explanation. But, I would like some more information regarding how to use Zabbix. I am somewhat confused regarding the same. Nagios has configuration files. But, I can't find anything of that sort in Zabbix. Any help regarding that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: You usually can find zabbix configuration files in
/etc/init.d/zabbix_agentd.conf
/etc/init.d/zabbix_server.conf
/etc/init.d/zabbix_java_gateway.conf
anyhow, you would need to understand how zabbix connect to tomcat